# When an answer is deleted change person listed as last modifier

Tags: feature-request, question-lists, last-activity

When an answer has been deleted the information on unanswered question tabs still says that users modification was the last to the thread. For instance on Stack Overflow right now the top two [Unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) are listed as having been modified by [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms).

[image]

While waiting for a moderator Zerkms, modified several answers in an effort to remove spam. However, once these answers were removed Zerkms still appears as the last person to modify the thread. While I imagine the hidden/deleted answers still exist somewhere causing this to occur, it can be confusing if you don't know why Zerkms is listed, as his modification is found nowhere within the linked question.

I would propose that when an answer / modification is deleted / rolled back, that the associated user is removed as the last modifier.

Comment: @Shog9 how does this become a duplicate 9 years later to a question asked 3 months after this one...... I realize your comment is from 7 years ago....

Comment: It's not; [that is a support question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75828/last-activity-on-question-shows-modified-by-user-who-did-not-ask-or-answer), explaining the reason for the behavior; this is a request to change the behavior. BTW, you can ping @ShadowWizard directly since he edited and unilaterally closed (either would make him eligible to receive notifications regarding the action).

Comment: I'm moving today's discussion with Servy [to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7553695#7553695).

Comment: @ahsteele sorry, I probably didn't look enough into it when re-closing, since it was already closed. I'll think twice in the future in similar cases. Also, you could have it reopened 6.5 years ago by editing/reopening (which would sent it to reopen review) or even flagging for mod attention.

Comment: @Shog9 To be fair, however, this was [reviewed "Leave Closed" in the review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/62888) before Shadow's clearing the reopen votes. Though it's possible that the system showed the minor edits after closure, which made people review the edit instead of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively we could have the community user own the latest activity (deletion). So then it would become:

> Modified by community 6-8 times ago

But it would even be better to replace the modified with a more descriptive word.