# Change last answerer on All Questions page when answer deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, homepage

The All Questions frontpage still shows the last answerer/editor, even if that answer was deleted.  This has been brought up as a [bug before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70024/when-an-answer-is-deleted-change-person-listed-as-last-modifier), so this is a feature-request to fix this.

The main reason it needs to be fixed is because if you delete a spam answer, it's good to be able to watch the frontpage to see if he creates another spam answer, but you keep seeing his name up there from his deleted answer.  It would really help spam hunting to have this fixed, so that when an answer is deleted, the message goes back to what it was prior to that answer.

Comment: Another reason to do this is to remove the username of a spammer/troll from the front page, which are not infrequently offensive on their own, e.g.,  [here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3900).